# Linux/SVN Annoying folder access problem

Tags: linux, svn

This is a annoying problem and I have no idea what is causing it. java and projects are two svn repository directories in /home/svn.

```
drwxrwSr-x 6 svn svn 4096 2010-10-19 19:36 java
drwxrwsr-x 6 svn svn 4096 2010-10-18 17:20 projects
```

They have the same permissions and files inside them have same permissions as well, which is drwxrwsr-x.

abc is a user who also a member of the svn group. I can access projects folder but on the java folder it says.

```
bash: cd: java/: Permission denied
```

Earlier I couldn't even access /home/svn folder through user abc, even though I been doing that for some time now

```
drwxrw-r-x  5 svn    svn    4096 2010-10-19 23:09 svn
```

I had to change permission of svn directory from drwxrw-r-x to drwxrwxr-x in order to access it as abc

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your java folder has the SGID-bit set with execute permission (see the capital S in your directory listing).
The project folder does not.

Use

```
chmod g-s java
chmod g+x java
chmod g+s java
```

to make it the same as the project folder

Comment: chmod g-s java
bit removed now it looks like 
drwxrw-r-x 6 svn svn 4096 2010-10-19 19:36 java
Though I still have the same problem. Project has a small "s". Is that different?

Answer (score 1):

The execute access bit `x` on directories allows to traverse the directory. It means tho when permissions are set to `drwxrw-r-x`, the group does not have traverse(execute) access right. As you are not user `svn`, but user `abc`, and `abc` is member of the `svn` group, user `abc` cannot traverse the directory. This results in the `Permission denied' message.